For which values of $\mu$ is the Standard Map $f_{\mu}(x,y)=(x+y+\frac{\mu}{2\pi} \sin (2\pi x),y+\frac{\mu}{2\pi}\sin (2\pi x))$ non wandering?
Let $f_{\mu}(x,y)=(x+y+\frac{\mu}{2\pi} \sin (2\pi x),y+\frac{\mu}{2\pi}\sin (2\pi x))$, with $\mu > 0$ and considered in the cylinder $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \times  \mathbb{R} $. For which values of the parameter $\mu$ is $f_{\mu}$ nonwandering?
